# How do I get the column and/or row of a value in a dynamic array, has 30 or 31 columns (depending on which month) and variable rows that are dyna

Tags: excel

I have a dynamic array... `=SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(F8#,"<>"),COUNTIF(G7#,"<>"))`
`F8` is a list (1 column many rows) of names that changes and is dynamic
`G7` is a list (1 row many columns) of days in a month that dynamic changes whether it is 30 days or 31.

`(r,c)` is like `(n,(30 or 31))`.

The array sequentially goes from 1 to y.. depending on the number of rows (i.e. n).  So if I have a list of 13, and it is Jun (30 days), then I have a matrix of 30 columns, 13 rows.  That go from 1 to 30 in row 1.  31 to 60 in row 2, etc...all the way to 390.

I have a separate column of numbers 1 to 390 (also dynamic).  I would like to apply a logic such that for a particular value in the array `r,c --> (13 x 30)`, It will return the relative column and/or row.

Comment: Better put some sample data then explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: =match will return col/row nr based on criteria

Comment: I have read your question a good five times now over the last few hours and have no idea what you're after.  I can figure out you've got a table with names in the left column and days of the month as column headers, you also have a list of numbers - 1 for each cell in the names/month header table.  But that last paragraph - you want to type something in against one of the numbers in the list of numbers and return a position in the table?  So number 1 will return the value from A1, 2 will return the number from A2 or B1 (imagining the table is headed the same as a worksheet)?

Comment: Come to think of it .... of the five questions you've asked since 2019 you've only replied with one comment for extra info and never given any feedback........